# Kendo multi select Autoclose not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am rendering a popup using bootstrap data-toggle and inside popup i have a kendo multi select. But my popup is closing every time when i select an Option from multi select .I already set the autoClose property of kendo multi select to false.
One more interesting point is that even though both option select and remove are triggering 'Change'  event of multi select ,I am having issue only when selecting an Option .

Somebody please assist.

Thanks in advance
Subin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#day_txt').multiselect({
            enableFiltering: true,
            enableHTML: true,
            buttonClass: 'form-control',
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            templates: {
                button: '<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="multiselect-selected-text"></span> &nbsp;<b class="fa fa-caret-down"></b></button>',
                ul: '<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu"></ul>',
                filter: '<li class="multiselect-item filter"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span><input class="form-control multiselect-search" type="text"></div></li>',
                filterClearBtn: '<span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default btn-white btn-grey multiselect-clear-filter" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times-circle red2"></i></button></span>',
                li: '<li><a tabindex="0"><label></label></a></li>',
                divider: '<li class="multiselect-item divider"></li>',
                liGroup: '<li class="multiselect-item multiselect-group"><label></label></li>'
            }
        });
```

You can use bootstrap multi-select plugin, this is how you can  do it but in order to use bootstrap multi-select you need to add the cdn url of css and js in your page..I recommend you to use bootstrap multiselect ...